# How do you do equational reasoning for user defined equational relations with agda-stdlib?

Tags: equality, agda, theorem-proving

agda-stdlib has facilities for doing equational reasoning for various specific library defined relations ([example](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.html)). It also has a type that identifies equality relations defined [here](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.Structures.html). What is the easiest way for me to get access to the same facilities for equational reason I get with propositional equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kit is defined in [`Relation.Binary.Reasoning.Setoid`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.Reasoning.Setoid.html).

You only need to define a proof `S` that your relation defines a `Setoid` and then you can `open import Relation.Binary.Reasoning.Setoid S` to get the equational reasoning combinators.